# Error running newly installed Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I tried to install Eclipse v.4.7.0 and when I try to run in this is what appears on my screen.

I've tried to find a solution to this but haven't found a suitable one yet.

I'm using Ubuntu Mate.

(for some reason I couldn't join the below text together but imagine it is, sorry)

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/*******/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/**********/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/*****/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.550.v20170928-1359/eclipse_1629.so
-startup /home/******/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata ee8023
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/*****/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

Comment: The screenshot does not appear in your post. Can you add it?

Comment: sorry, the error message is now up

Comment: It does not look like Eclipse 4.7.0: `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` exists since 4.7.1a (assuming you did not tweak `eclipse.ini`) and `v20170928` means September 2017 whereas 4.7.0 has been released June 2017. Could you please tell which Eclipse version and package do you try to install on which Ubuntu version?